# Can Google provide voice prints for recognizing user speaking to Google Home

Tags: actions-on-google

For my conversation actions, would like to authenticate the user before he can utilize my services to ensure he is the true user and not anyone else. Can Google provide voice prints to recognize the person whose speaking to Google Home?

Am confident that Google must be recording voice. So it would be really helpful for authentication if its shared.

Answer (score 0):

While they do record your voice (you can see and hear a copy of all requests done via voice), they do not pass this on to services. They also are not (currently, anyway) trying to do user identification based on voice.